# iOS invalid rect for view in NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm Implementing pick-pop funtionality in my simple iOS app. I have a CustomView inside my MainViewController which in turns is wrapped in a NavigationController.
this custom view has a CollectionView which i want to implement pick-pop on its items 
now when i pick and pop on one item the rect preview is misplaced (see pictures)

[image: my view]
[image: misplaced pick and pop]
there are some more problems here which looks irrelevant to pick-pop functionality

first if i call `self.frame.origin.x` and `self.frame.origin.y` in my customView the result is `0` and `0` which is awkward as it is inside a navigationController

second the `location` parameter passed in

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
```

is also misplaced.( offset is exactly equal to navigationBar Height and left margin of my customView )

I passed the MainController to my CustomView and my customView is like this:

```
class CategoryView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate , MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate , UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate{

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryGrid: UICollectionView!

var callback:((Category)->Void)?;
var category:Category?;
var controller:UIViewController?{
    didSet{
        if(controller?.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available){
            controller?.registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: (controller?.view)!)
        }
    }
};
....
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let indexPath = categoryGrid?.indexPathForItem(at: location) else {
        return nil
    }

    if let cell = categoryGrid?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategoryViewCell {

        if let ret = getNextView(to: cell.category!){
            ret.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
            print(self);
            print(self.frame);
            previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame;
            return ret;
        }
        return nil;
    }
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true);
    return nil
}


}
```

can any one tell whats wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting the frame for preview, please show code

Comment: @user1000 I added the related method to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transform the cell bounds to the coordinates of the `sourceView` , e. g.:

```
previewingContext.sourceRect = 
    previewingContext.sourceView.convert(cell.bounds, from: cell)
```

You shouldn't rely on the cell's frame. It is a much cleaner approach to transform the coordinates from one view to another.

Comment: `previewingContext.sourceView` is readOnly and `cell.bounds.origin.x` and `cell.bounds.origin.y` is always 0 which turns out my pick rect is always in top left corner

Comment: Sorry, you can convert the cell rect to the source view, too. I've edited my post.

Comment: thanks @macmoonshine it's working now but how to convert the function parameter `location` to my custom view coordinates. it has the same offset when i need to call `categoryGrid?.cellForItem(at: indexPath)`

Comment: There exists a conversion method for points as well. Try something like `cell.convert(location, from: previewingContext.sourceView)`.